# Group table cells together in html with ul li?

Tags: html, html-lists

I want to make something like this but without tr th attributes of html since my table im using only ul and li attributes

```
+-----------------------+
|   one joint column    |
+-----------------------+
|  5  |  6  |   joint   | 
+-----------------------+
|  9  |  10 |  11 | 12  |
+-----------------------+
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

here's my code snippet :

```
<li class="cell"> 1min
    <div ng-repeat="load1min in cpu.data1mnList | orderBy:'idEquipment'">
        <span class="bolded_span">
            {{(load1min.value).toFixed(3)}}
        </span>

    </div>
</li>
<li class="cell"> 5min
    <div ng-repeat="load5min in cpu.data5mnList  | orderBy:'idEquipment'">
        <span class="bolded_span">
            {{(load5min.value).toFixed(3)}}
        </span>
    </div>

</li>
<li class="cell"> 15min
    <div ng-repeat="load15min in cpu.data15mnList  | orderBy:'idEquipment'">
        <span class="bolded_span">
            {{(load15min.value).toFixed(3)}}
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to group this 3 cells with one title above them

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: If your data is tablular you should be using tables, if your date is a list the ul/li should be sufficient. Why are you doing this approach?

Comment: Here's what i've done : https://ibb.co/sC1KZB1, here's how the result should be :
https://ibb.co/J5qh9wN.
Tried few tricks with css but I always end up with grouping the 3 columns in one column

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I posted an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS flex

```css
.flex {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex > * { flex-basis: 100%; }
.span-1 { flex-basis: 25%; }
.span-2 { flex-basis: 50%; }

li { background: gold; }
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li>one joint column</li>
  <li class="span-1">5</li>
  <li class="span-1">6</li>
  <li class="span-2">joint</li>
  <li class="span-1">9</li>
  <li class="span-1">10</li>
  <li class="span-1">11</li>
  <li class="span-1">12</li>
</ul>
```

Another way:

```css
.flex {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex > * { flex-basis: 25%; }
.span-2 { flex-basis: 50%; }
.span-4 { flex-basis: 100%; }

.flex li { background: gold;}
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li class="span-4">one joint column</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li class="span-2">joint</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! just a question, why text-align: center; doesnt really center that one joint column ?

Comment: @akadri01 use `.flex li {text-align: center;}` is you want to align text to center

Comment: That's what I did, it was woking just didn't see it right, thank a lot man!